# Showposts 30 but 10 per page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have now this piece of code to show on each page `10 posts` but know I want still the same but the maximum of posts in total can only be `30`.

How do I do this?

```
 <?php query_posts('showposts=10&paged='.$paged);?>
```

Comment: Try changing the `10` into a `30`?

Comment: `page * limit <= 30`.

Comment: But then i have 30posts per page and if i have 32posts in total it wil just keep showing

Comment: where should i place this? page * limit <= 30

Comment: Add a condition on the page which will check and fetch the data.

Comment: It's not working it will just show 30 posts and no pagination

Comment: Just use if condition to check if page is greater than 3.

I checked it and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is code where you want to display the post:

```
<?php  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 10,'paged' => $paged);
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    print_r($post); ?>
    <h1> <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></h1>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <h3><?php the_content(); ?></h3>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

This is footer where you need to display pagination.

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
<?php if($loop->max_num_pages>1){?>
<ul class="pager">
<?php for($i=1;$i<=$loop->max_num_pages; $i++){ ?>
<li><a href="<?php  get_permalink();?>page/<?php echo $i; ?>"> <?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use wp_query to retrieve the posts, like Pieter Goosen said, is more efficient. Also wp_query have a property called $max_num_page that you can use to limit the number of pages you get.

You can modify your pagination to something like this:

```
        global $wp_query;

        if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ){
            $current_page = max( 1, get_query_var('paged') );
            $max_pages = 3;
            $args = array(
              'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
              'format' => '/paged/%#%',
              'current' => $current_page,
              'total' => $max_pages,
              'show_all' => false,
              'type' => 'array',
              'paged' => 1
            );
            $pages = paginate_links( $args );
            if (is_array($pages)) {
                $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') == 0) ? 1 : get_query_var('paged');
                foreach( $pages as $page) {
                    echo "$page";
                }
            }
         }
```

I have also found [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56284/limit-the-number-of-pages-created-by-the-paging). This code seems to work and you don't need to change any of your current code:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'limit_pages');
function limit_pages($query) {

    $query->max_num_pages = 3;
    if ($query->query_vars['paged'] > 3) {
        $query->query_vars['paged'] = 3;
        $query->query['paged'] = 3;
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: I also thought of this approach (this would be inline with my bullet point one). The problem is, most people don't like this approach as you can still manually request page 4 (or any other after that) and still get posts if there where more than thirty to begin with. If you can live with this, your approach is great.

Comment: See the second code I add @Pieter Goosen. Do you know if you can still retrieve page 4 with this code? I have not tested it, but I think this limit the query before doing it and it will only retrieve 3 pages.